# How to limit height of child view in an expandable list view android?

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I am trying to limit height of child view of an `Expandable-list-view`. Such that when parent view is clicked the child view can be show in certain limited height .

User can view all the child's consisting in that child view using scroll.

I altered the height of convert view in getChildView(), but it alters the height of individual child rather than whole view.

Please help with your suggestions.

Thanks in advance.